# Google Map AJAX loading issue in IE

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating an adaptive map for responsive web design, basically for non-handheld screens I load in an interactive Google Map (full Google Map API v3) and for handheld screens I show a static Google Map image. It works fine in all browsers except IE 8/9, it sort of works in IE but mostly not e.g. first attempt it will load then after a few refreshes or sometimes a 2nd refresh it won't show (it's very random), IE 8 is worse than 9, 9 usually won't break until around 7-8 refreshes. But they both output the same error in the console:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'initialize' 
main.js, line 9 character 238
```

Which is referring to the Google Map API JavaScript file.

So here's the stripped back function:

```
$.fn.adaptiveMap = function() {

// Set variables
var mapContainer = $(this);

// If palm sized screen
if (isPalmSizedScreen) {
    mapContainer.html('<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.867487,151.20699&zoom=15&markers=-33.867487,151.20699&size=650x405&sensor=false" class="map__static frame">');
}
// If not palm sized screen
else {
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&sensor=false&callback=initialize');

    mapContainer.load('/Cheetah/includes/modules/widgets/google-map3.php');
}

}
```

Then on document ready I call the function:

`$('.map').adaptiveMap();`

Here's the contents of the file being AJAX'd in:

```
<div class="map__dynamic frame">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867487,151.20699);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: false
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    var contentString = 
        '<div class="infowindow">'+
            '<div>'+
                    '<p class="mrg-off"><strong>SALES OFFICE:</strong><br>1/16 M. 5<br>Tambol Cherngthaley<br>Amphur Thalang<br>Phuket, 83110.<br>See <a href="contact">contact</a> page.</p>'
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    ;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
</script>
```

I know I need to call the API before AJAX'ing the file via the `callback` parameter in the API URL, I think IE has some problem with this? I realise this could be done better but as I said it is working fine in all browsers bar IE. The main thing is I need to make sure that none of the bloated API stuff is being downloaded for handheld screens (mobile) as I'm building Mobile first, currently this isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&sensor=false&callback=initialize');

mapContainer.load('/Cheetah/includes/modules/widgets/google-map3.php');
```

The google maps api is calling the `initialize` function which exists inside the `google-map3.php` file you retrieve by AJAX.  The reason it works sometimes but not others is because the `.load` method finishes before `.getScript` so the `initialize` function exists.  Once the browser has the script in cache the `initialize` function will be called before the file has downloaded.

If you retrieve the script after the AJAX reqeust by putting in a callback function that is run on file download completion it should work every time.

```
mapContainer.load('/Cheetah/includes/modules/widgets/google-map3.php', function() {
     $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-KEY&sensor=false&callback=initialize');
});
```